# How get the count of object that is inside another object in C#?

Tags: c#

Application class has Applicant object:

```
  public class Application
 { 
  public virtual ICollection<Applicant.Applicant> Applicants { get; set; }
 ...
 }
```

Applicant class has Employee object as collection:

```
 public class Applicant
{
   public virtual ICollection<Employment> Employments { get; set; }
 }
```

How I can get the count of Employment in this method:

```
  public void InsertApplication(Application application)
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use `application.SelectMany(a=>a.Applicants.SelectMany(x=>x.Employments)).Count()`

Answer (score 0):

An `Applicant`'s `Employment` count can be retrieved using the [`Count` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/5s3kzhec.aspx)...

```
applicant.Employments.Count
```

An `Application`'s `Employment` count is the [sum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb535184.aspx) of each `Applicant`'s `Employment` count...

```
application.Applicants.Sum(applicant => applicant.Employments.Count);
```